# How to retrieve the original Percolator query

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to use the Percolator and retrieve not only the perculator id but the whole original query.

This is my query:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/my-index/.percolator/1' -d '{
    "query" : {
        "match" : {
            "message" : "bonsai tree"
        }
    },
    "moreInfo": {
        "foo": "bar"
    }
}'
```

When a matching document is found, I get this:

```
{
    "took" : 19,
    "_shards" : {
        "total" : 5,
        "successful" : 5,
        "failed" : 0
    },
    "total" : 1,
    "matches" : [
        {
             "_index" : "my-index",
             "_id" : "1"
        }
    ]
}
```

What I realy interested in, is the `moreInfo` part of the query. I know I can query elasticsearch for it in an additional request, but it would be great to just have it directly, something like this:

```
{
    "took" : 19,
    "_shards" : {
        "total" : 5,
        "successful" : 5,
        "failed" : 0
    },
    "total" : 1,
    "matches" : [
        {
        "query" : {
            "match" : {
                "message" : "bonsai tree"
            }
        },
        "moreInfo": {
            "foo": "bar"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very good point, retrieving the query directly is not possible at the moment but it's something that we might want to add soon as you're not the only one asking for it and it makes a lot of sense. There's an issue open that describes this usecase already: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/4317